# Block ONLY Google Ads

Tags: blocking, hosts, advertisements

There is an easy way to disable ONLY ads by Google (like this: https://p1.picsto.re/2013-10-06_111448.png )? Using hosts file (I hate Adblock or other bloatware tools) is quite easy but what are the lines which block Google ads? After some time spent with searching, just didn`t find any usable information. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are willing to research what advertising company and URL that google used, there is no really "easy" way to do it. You are doing a targeted block against a certain advertising company, so basically you need to know some wildcard address that Google uses (say one example I happen to know on top of my head is *.adwords.* which is owned by Google).

Adblock / AdblockPlus has done the research, and prepared the blocking on your behalf.